# How to use angularjs to check for data save after dropdown change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog

Very new to AngularJS; and Stack, so I hope I am phrasing this correctly.

A SPA with editable text inputs.
Two select drop-downs control what data is shown, one for time period and other for location.
Data displayed changes depending on what is selected in dropdowns.

How to I check the page for changes to the data and warn the user of unsaved changes (if any) when/after they click one of the dropdowns to load new data?  e.g. form displays one location's data, user changes it but then when they click the drop down to change to another location (without saving first) to load/see new data, they need to be warned that there is unsaved data....

Any and all hints and help are appreciated.

Comment: paste your code. what have you tried and what problem are you facing?

Comment: From what I understand, you have a form which consists of 2 dropdown control. Changing value on either one will change data in some other control and you need to alert user if the data is not saved. But what data is changing and where is still missing. still on a generic level, what you can try is, have a flag, which gets set when either dropdown is changed and on onChange event of these dropdown, check for this flag and process accordingly.

Comment: I have no code to offer because i have no idea where to start in this.  I have a SPA with 2 dropdowns and multiple text inputs.  The data displayed in the inputs is based on what is selected in the dropdowns (time period & location).  I am trying to research; how do I warned the user of unsaved data in the page, when they change a selection in the dropwdown (which will load new data and overwrite what is in the inputs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save selected object to json like

```
angular.toJson
```

and then check if new object matches stored one in `ng-change`.
Here is my small demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/XMRM3mxKyO5rVD646BJa?p=preview